# accesing i18n resources from tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium

I have a problem folks with internationalising my selenium tests.  I have a web app deployed in a tomcat container on a test machine.  I want to run the selenium tests on a seperate computer using the test machine.  The problem is all the locale files for my internationalisation are on this test machine.  Right now i have these files added as resources to my selenium tests but is there a way i can access these files currently in the container in any way.  Is it possible to configure tomcat so i can access this directory through a URL for example or some other way.  Im open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

URL's for accessing resource in jar in file system are such as:

jar:file:/C:/maven/repository/org/easymock/easymock/3.0/easymock-3.0.jar!/META-INF/INDEX.LIST

If disc location is not known you can access resources via ClassLoader, but they are searched only in specified directories: current war, tomcat shared libs, JRE libs